# Problem with regexp pattern. Deleteing HTML <link> tags

Tags: java, mysql, sql, regex, xml

I need to use regexp to delete from huge text wall all between tag `<link>`. I used something like this : `<link\s[\w*\W*]*css"\s\/>` but it alsbo selecting all between those tags. Example:

```
<link link crossorigin="crossorigin" href="some random href" more random text /css" /> some content that should not be delated <link link crossorigin="crossorigin" href="some random href" more random text /css" />
```

I will need something like this also with  tags. Should I take my regexp into `()` group? I need to remove those parts from huge product description to create XML in Java (taking all data from MySQL database). Any guidance or tips?

Comment: Parse the document and delete its `link` elements by dedicated methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<link[^>]*>` to delete everything from `<link` to the closing `>`.  However, it is better to use a dedicated xml parser for this task.